# How to migrate from DB2 to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, db2, migration

I have an existing Windows DB2 database that I'd like to move onto PostgreSQL.  The users for the application can live with a weekend's worth of downtime.  What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

Create a test system with a DB2 and a Postgres server. Try the migration (ideally with some real data from one of your backups). Make sure it works. Create a script that automates the process - and make sure that works, too.

Then, on migration day, set up a redirection to a static HTML page, stop the server, make a backup, run your script. Check that everything went ok.

- If not, restore the backup.
- If yes, start the server.

Make sure, that it works, too.

- Remove the redirection.